# Spanning repeatable keys

Tags: functional-programming, tuples, erlang, maps, elixir

from such:

```js
[
  {"Caerus1", "Ramses Refiner"},
  {"Caerus1", "Jupiter Refiner"},
  {"Caerus1", "Jupiter Other"},
  {"Caerus1", "Trader 13"},
  {"Caerus1", "Cathode Supplier 4"},
  {"Dionysus3", "Cathode Supplier 4"},
  {"Dionysus3", "Ramses Refiner"},
  {"Dionysus3", "Trader 13"},
  {"Dionysus3", "Jupiter Refiner"},
  {"Dionysus3", "Jupiter Other"},
  {"Prometheus2", "Jupiter Other"},
  {"Prometheus2", "Ramses Refiner"},
  {"Prometheus2", "Trader 13"},
  {"Prometheus2", "Cathode Supplier 4"},
  {"Prometheus2", "Jupiter Refiner"}
]
```

I'd like to achieve this:

```js
[
  {"Caerus1" => ["Ramses Refiner", "Jupiter Refiner", "Jupiter Other", "Trader 13", "Cathode Supplier 4"]},
   .
   .
   .
]
```

So basically converting these tuples into a map with unique key - so it doesn't repeat (that I can do easily) the hard part is making a list of the 2nd element strings.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Elixir it's quite easy with [Enum.group_by/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3):

```
iex> Enum.group_by(values, fn {key, _} -> key end, fn {_, value} -> value end)
%{
  "Caerus1" => ["Ramses Refiner", "Jupiter Refiner", "Jupiter Other",
   "Trader 13", "Cathode Supplier 4"],
  "Dionysus3" => ["Cathode Supplier 4", "Ramses Refiner", "Trader 13",
   "Jupiter Refiner", "Jupiter Other"],
  "Prometheus2" => ["Jupiter Other", "Ramses Refiner", "Trader 13",
   "Cathode Supplier 4", "Jupiter Refiner"]
}
```

Comment: Also: `input |> Enum.group_by(&elem(&1, 0), &elem(&1, 1))`.

Comment: Also: `for {k, v} <- input, reduce: %{}, do: (acc -> Map.update(acc, k, [v], &[v | &1]))`

Answer (score 3):

```
1> L_tup = [
1>   {"Caerus1", "Ramses Refiner"},
1>   {"Caerus1", "Jupiter Refiner"},
1>   {"Caerus1", "Jupiter Other"},
1>   {"Caerus1", "Trader 13"},
1>   {"Caerus1", "Cathode Supplier 4"},
1>   {"Dionysus3", "Cathode Supplier 4"},
1>   {"Dionysus3", "Ramses Refiner"},
1>   {"Dionysus3", "Trader 13"},
1>   {"Dionysus3", "Jupiter Refiner"},
1>   {"Dionysus3", "Jupiter Other"},
1>   {"Prometheus2", "Jupiter Other"},
1>   {"Prometheus2", "Ramses Refiner"},
1>   {"Prometheus2", "Trader 13"},
1>   {"Prometheus2", "Cathode Supplier 4"},
1>   {"Prometheus2", "Jupiter Refiner"}
1> ].
[{"Caerus1","Ramses Refiner"},
 {"Caerus1","Jupiter Refiner"},
 {"Caerus1","Jupiter Other"},
 {"Caerus1","Trader 13"},
 {"Caerus1","Cathode Supplier 4"},
 {"Dionysus3","Cathode Supplier 4"},
 {"Dionysus3","Ramses Refiner"},
 {"Dionysus3","Trader 13"},
 {"Dionysus3","Jupiter Refiner"},
 {"Dionysus3","Jupiter Other"},
 {"Prometheus2","Jupiter Other"},
 {"Prometheus2","Ramses Refiner"},
 {"Prometheus2","Trader 13"},
 {"Prometheus2","Cathode Supplier 4"},
 {"Prometheus2","Jupiter Refiner"}]
2> F = fun({K,V},Acc) ->                  
2>     case Acc of                        
2>         [#{K:=L}|T] -> [#{K=>[V|L]}|T];
2>         Acc -> [#{K => [V]}|Acc]       
2>     end                                
2> end.                                   
#Fun<erl_eval.43.79398840>
3> lists:foldl(F,[],L_tup).
[#{"Prometheus2" =>
       ["Jupiter Refiner","Cathode Supplier 4","Trader 13",
        "Ramses Refiner","Jupiter Other"]},
 #{"Dionysus3" =>
       ["Jupiter Other","Jupiter Refiner","Trader 13",
        "Ramses Refiner","Cathode Supplier 4"]},
 #{"Caerus1" =>
       ["Cathode Supplier 4","Trader 13","Jupiter Other",
        "Jupiter Refiner","Ramses Refiner"]}]
4>
```

if the initial list L_tup is not sorted it is necessary to use lists:sort(L_tup).

The former code will have a result looking like the example you give: a list of map. But it is not a map as described in the last sentence. To create a map you can use the next code (this version does not need a sorted input):

```
4> F1 = fun({K,V},M) ->       
4>     L = maps:get(K,M,[]), 
4>     M#{K=>[V|L]}          
4> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.43.79398840>
5> lists:foldl(F1,#{},L_tup).
#{"Caerus1" =>
      ["Cathode Supplier 4","Trader 13","Jupiter Other",
       "Jupiter Refiner","Ramses Refiner"],
  "Dionysus3" =>
      ["Jupiter Other","Jupiter Refiner","Trader 13",
       "Ramses Refiner","Cathode Supplier 4"],
  "Prometheus2" =>
      ["Jupiter Refiner","Cathode Supplier 4","Trader 13",
       "Ramses Refiner","Jupiter Other"]}
6> % could be written in a single line :o)
6> % lists:foldl(fun({K,V},M) -> M#{K=>[V|maps:get(K,M,[])]} end,#{},L_tup).
```

Comment: Not an erlang user, what `:=` does exactly?

Comment: This is not working

Comment: It works. This text is a copy/paste from werl console, but it need the version 23 or higher of erlang. If you have an older version the first case statement: `[#{K:=L}|T] -> [#{K=>[V|L]}|T];` is not allowed. The second example, which return a map as you require in your text, should work with earlier versions.

Comment: To have a complete explanation of what `:=` does, I suggest you go to the documentation [map-expressions](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#map-expressions). In short it does roughly the same thing than `=>` in a map, but requires that the key already exists. It is why you must use this notation in pattern matching.

Comment: @akad you put a tag [tag:erlang] and then you ask what `:=` does in the erlang solution and even claim the perfectly working code not working? This is ridiculous. | Upvoted, ofc.

Comment: I did research the docs and obviously didn't put erlang tags in elixir, translated it to working solution finally but for some time it returned unexpected solution. Thanks for the help anyways